WebRTC - Once Remote video play starts ducking happens to current stream in Android Webview
I am using Android's webview for a webrtc video application. I am observing a behaviour where device audio is getting reduced when the remote video starts playing.
Is there any way to avoid ducking in this scenario ? Also are there any instances where the audio could be less even if

device outbound bitrate is high
network is good at both sides
both devices are functioning well

How to resolve this issue from android side ? If i try to use volume for stream, i am not able to get the current stream, but can set to stream_voice_call based on the audioManager api to check.
Can any settings to be made on webview side as well ?
